# populate rows of programatically created asp:table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m creating one Empty `asp:Table` in design view.

Pro-grammatically I am adding `row` to this `table`.
This rows contains various `custom controls`. for e.g combination of (`text box & dropDownList`).

Initially I m adding all `control` to `rows` & finally into `table`.
Its properly displaying.
After changing the values inside custom control's I want to save that value in `database` on button click event.

On that click event I want to iterate through that table for all rows which i have added.
but on click event I am always getting empty table.

On net I search regarding this, but every one telling that you have to re-create table.

is their any way in which without re-creating the all rows I'll get all rows. so that from that rows I can save changed values to database.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a `GridView` with TemplateFields which would simplify that task a lot? In general: no, there's no way to avoid recreating controls since they are disposed as soon as they are rendered to the client. That's not an ASP.NET issue, this is the way HTTP works.

Comment: you can use gridview instead of table.

Comment: Echoing what @TimSchmelter said, use a GridView instead of a Table. Are you databinding on your table anywhere?

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said use Gridview instead of Table,it will be easy to use also.

Comment: Table re-creation is not a problem. But As i m using various custom controls e.g combo box. set of multiple check box as one control. Here I want to keep changed status of each control inside row so that on next time after display it will show  changed values. If any one have any link for example regarding this(using Grid view) then please post it .

Comment: Now I m using Grid view and adding custom control on it. I just want to add event handler for this control. eg. I am having (TextBox + DropDownList) Control. for this I m adding text change & selecteIndexChange event.... but this event are not firing.. I don't know what is the problem